# Fill formula in C2 to corresponding last row of the B column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a new project and new to VBA. I have to fill formula to C2 to last row on the B column. my code as below

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2").Select
Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb]Data'!$B$1:$J$65530,9,0)"
```

This prompt me as error 1004 - method range or object global failed

Pls suggest me to way forward.

Comment: what is the sheet's name that you want your fomula in ? also, to which sheet are you looking to find your `LastRow` ?

Comment: I am in sheet2.

Comment: `sheet2` is the name of your worksheet ? or your index ? you are trying to use `Vlookup` to look for values in corresponding value in Column B to another workbook named `Tracking Sheet Opens` ?

Comment: I am working in sheet 2 and my look up table is in Tracking sheet.

Comment: not according to your code, in your code you have `'[Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb]Data'!` , it means you are trying to look at worksheet "Data" in another workbook "Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb" (saved as `.xlsb`) . are both of your worksheets in the same workbook ?

Comment: If you want to fill down to the last row within column B, then you should change the `LastRow` variable to `xlUp` on column B. `LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks that's worked well. But now my result shown only =VLOOKUP(B2,'[Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb]Data'!$B$1:$J$65530,9,0) to all my rows? I want answer to be displayed

Comment: @Saran try the code in my answer below, see if it works like you intended

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from the PO if the searched range in the `VLookup` is in "Tracking" sheet in the same workbook, or it's in "Data" sheet in another workbook named "Tracking Sheet Opens" ,so my answer covers both scenarios.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyVLookupFormulaDown()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' find last row with data in Column A in "Sheet2"
    'LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' from post maybe need to look for last row in Column B
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Option 1: check value of cell B2 in "sheet2" with the range
    ' in sheet "Data" in another workbook named "Tracking Sheet Opens"
    .Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb]Data'!$B$1:$J$65530,9,0)"


    ' Option 2: check value of cell B2 in "sheet2" with the range
    ' in sheet "Tracking" in the same workbook
    .Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Tracking'!$B$1:$J$65530,9,0)"

    ' same line for both options, copy formula down
    .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).FillDown

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai,thanks for your comments. It worked well. But the results shows only forumla not a result.  means shows only  - =VLOOKUP(B2,'[Tracking Sheet Opens.xlsb]Data'!$B$1:$J$65530,9,0)" in all rows in C column

Comment: @Saran if your porblem is not solved, i would like to try and help, but I think i am missing some information here. 1. what are the names of the worksheets ? the sheet with this formula ("Sheet2") ,and where lies the whole data ? what it's sheet nanme ? are both sheets in the same workbook ?

Comment: 1. File I am working on Testing 2. lookup value date is Tracking Sheet Opens Sheet name I am working is Sheet 1

Comment: I have updated coding as follows:  Now its workings fine.Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Master Data'!A:B,2,0)"
            
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
               
              
       Range("C2:C" & LastRow).FillDown.

Comment: @Saran instead of putting it here as a comment, you can answer you own question, just add another `Answer` here with your working code. hope I've helped